# placing coins on a table with a twist.

Tags: geometry, puzzle

consider the classical puzzle, on a circular table, you and a friend take turns placing coins on the table and the first person who cannot do this loses.

You can guarantee winning by placing the first coin in the centre and then maintain symmetry.

Notice this strategy is independent of the table size. (i.e. the radius of the circle)

So I asked myself the question:

Does there exists a table shape such that the 2nd player has a winning strategy provided the table is large enough?

The answer is yes, and an annulus is an example.

My new question is does there exists a shape, topologically the same as a disc, for which, provided the table is large enough, the 2nd player is always guaranteed to win?

(Consider two circles connected by a really thin rod, so thin that you cannot place a coin on the rod. In this case there is a strategy for the 2nd player to win by maintaining symmetry. However, if you enlarge the table proportionally, the thin rod will becomes thick enough for the first player to be able to place a coin at the middle of the thin rod, and maintain symmetry afterward, thereby guaranteeing a win. I wonder if there exists a shape, with no holes, for which the second player is guaranteed to win, for all 'sufficiently large' tables.)

Comment: @DanielRust okay. sorry

Comment: Ahha, so you want the table to be a simply connected subspace of the plane? (Topologically the same as a circle means something slightly different and isn't what I think you meant - you maybe meant topologically the same as the disk?)

Comment: Although it doesn't match your criteria (as it's not homeomorphic to a disk), it's interesting to note that on a sphere, player two wins by symmetry.

Comment: @DanielRust I mean a disc, yes. I wanted to avoid using 'topologically the same' for the reason I don't really understand topology that well. And yeah, nice example with the sphere.

Comment: As a small lemma: if $U\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is our simply connected region, then if $U$ has a degree-$2$ automorphism (isometry) with exactly one fixed point, then there exists an $r$ small enough such that if the game is being played with coins of radius $r$, then player $1$ can force a win (a bound on $r$ is given by the largest $r$ such that $B_r(p)\subset U$ where $p$ is the fixed point of the automorphism.)

Comment: In fact the above holds for any totally bounded metric space, not just bounded simply connected regions in the plane.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, two discs touching in exactly one point are a simply connected shape for which second player has a winning strategy by symmetry.
I think the requirement best capturing the spirit of a table would be convexity.

Comment: Could the shape of the table theoretically by asymmetric? Because that would eliminate the first players original winning strategy.